# Как случайным образом поставить Button-ы по всему экрану?

Tags: android

Пусть у меня есть `n` Button-ов. И я должен их расставить по экрану в рандомном порядке. Они не должны пересекаться или покрывать друг друга. После небольшого поиска ответа я нашел решение [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144690/how-to-display-a-button-in-random-screen-position)
Но это мне не особо помогло. Вот мой код:

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root) ;

    DisplayMetrics displaymatrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymatrics);

    for(int i = 1 ; i<=n ; i++) {
        Button b = new Button(this) ;

        b.setText("A");

        b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dpToPx(65),dpToPx(65)));

        Random R = new Random();

        float dx = R.nextFloat() * displaymatrics.widthPixels;

        float dy = R.nextFloat() * displaymatrics.heightPixels;

        b.animate().x(dx).y(dy).setDuration(0).start();

        l.addView(b);

    }


}
private int dpToPx(int dp) {

    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

Но проблема в том что много кнопок скрываются за пределами экрана или вообще пересекаются. Как решить такого рода задачу?

А также пробовал этот метод. Но не все button-ы видны.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root) ;

    DisplayMetrics displaymatrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymatrics);


    Log.d("tag" , "width and height: " + displaymatrics.widthPixels + " " + displaymatrics.heightPixels) ;


    for(int i = 1 ; i<=10 ; i++) {

        Button b = new Button(this) ;

        b.setText(i+" ");

        b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dpToPx(65),dpToPx(65)));

        Random R = new Random();

        int dx = R.nextInt(displaymatrics.widthPixels - dpToPx(65)) ;

        int dy = R.nextInt(displaymatrics.heightPixels - dpToPx(65));

        Log.d("tag","dx,dy:" + " " +  dx + " " + dy ) ;

        b.animate().x(dx).y(dy).setDuration(0).start();

        l.addView(b);

    }
      }
```

Comment: *у меня есть n Button-ов. И я должен их расставить по экрану в рандомном порядке* Первый вопрос - размеры экрана и батонов таковы, что батоны гарантированно поместятся на экране, как не раскидывай, или возможен вариант, когда последний (а то и не последний) батон просто некуда будет втиснуть? Второй вопрос - положение должно быть полностью рандомным, или некоторая дискретность узлов сетки допустима?

Comment: @Akina Количество button-ов максимум 15 и их размеры не такие большие. Они гарантированно поместятся. Положение должно быть полностью рандомным и button-ы не должны пересекаться или покрывать друг-друга или выходить за рамки экрана. 
Мои параметры: 
`displaymatrics.widthPixels = 720; 
displaymatrics.heightPixels = 1280;
` 
По совету @Asidert сделал так как он и все генерируемые числа меньше параметров на верху. Но многие button-ы не видны. Почему?

Comment: Для исключения пересечений можно использовать подход регистрации занятых регионов. Для 720x1280 массив занятых регионов получится не очень большим. Для очередного батона генерится одна координата - порядковый **линейный** номер незанятого региона (от 1 до 720*1280 минус количество занятых координат). После генерации очередной координаты все занимаемые батоном координаты, а также координаты, при помещении в которые ещё одного батона он пересечётся с текущим, помечаются как недоступные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения проблемы ухода кнопок за экран:

Меняем `LinearLayout` на `RelativeLayout`, далее:

```
Random R = new Random();
int dx = R.nextInt(displaymatrics.widthPixels-dpToPx(65));
int dy = R.nextInt(displaymatrics.heightPixels-dpToPx(65));
//Это будут отступы от левого края и верхнего
//65 - твои размеры кнопки
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(dpToPx(65), dpToPx(65));
params.setMargins(dx, dy, 0, 0);
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Не помогло. Написал так: `int dx = R.nextInt(displaymatrics.widthPixels - dpToPx(65)) ;

            int dy = R.nextInt(displaymatrics.heightPixels - dpToPx(65));`

Почему `nextInt` использовать ?

Comment: @andy11 `int` или `float` особого значения не имеет, но смысл использовать дробные числа там где они не нужны? Как именно ты определил что не помогло?

Comment: Из 10 Button-ов только 2-3 видны. Остальные за экраном. Некоторые видны на половину. 
width и height девайса: 720x1280
А также все генерируемые числа не превосходят их. Так в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @andy11 покажи весь код добавления кнопок на экран.

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: @andy11 обновил ответ, попробуй так.

Comment: Спасибо,но AbsoluteLayout deprecated ведь? Я не могу его использовать

Comment: @andy11 совсем забыл про это... Как вариант можно использовать `RelativeLayout` и выставлять случайный `margin`

Comment: @andy11 подправил ответ, попробуй

Comment: Почему `right,bottom margin`  равны нулю? Они у меня все равно переплетаются. А также некоторых вовсе нет. Но результат лучше предыдущего.Теперь нужно написать алгоритм чтобы дистанция каждой от другой была такой,что они не покрывали друг друга. Приму ваш ответ. Но прошу еще направить на правильную дорогу))

Comment: @andy11 переплетаться они будут в любом случае, т.к. нет кода проверяющего наложение. Равны нулю т.к. координатная сетка идет слева свехру.

Comment: @andy11 Вроде как, можно получить координаты кнопки и дальше сверять их с координатами других кнопок. На англоязычном форуме уже были подобные вопросы, один из них: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203740/retrieve-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-button-in-android#, надеюсь поможет.